# Exception while giving context:annotation-config

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to spring. While trying I was able to set autowiring from the xml configuration using

```
<bean id="triangle" class="com.spring.sample.Triangle" autowire="byName"/>
```

And also I tried with @autowire annotation which was successful while defining the bean like

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
```

But when I tried using `<context:annotation-config />` i got the following exception.

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:70)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.sample.MainSpringClass.main(MainSpringClass.java:17)
```

I found this issue in several questions in StackOverflow but none of them provide a solid answer.

```
JDK version :1.8.0_144
Spring framework: 3.2.0.RELEASE
```

the Spring XML config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
    http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="triangle" class="com.spring.sample.Triangle">     
    </bean>

    <bean id="pointA" class="com.spring.sample.Point">
        <property name="x" value="10" />
        <property name="y" value="$10" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="pointB" class="com.spring.sample.Point">
        <property name="x" value="20" />
        <property name="y" value="20" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="pointC" class="com.spring.sample.Point">
        <property name="x" value="30" />
        <property name="y" value="30" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean> -->
        <context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

And finally the Bean Triangle

```
public class Triangle {

    @Autowired
    private Point pointA;
    @Autowired
    private Point pointB;
    @Autowired
    private Point pointC;

    public Point getPointA() {
        return pointA;
    }

    public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
    }

    public Point getPointB() {
        return pointB;
    }

    public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
        this.pointB = pointB;
    }

    public Point getPointC() {
        return pointC;
    }

    public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
        this.pointC = pointC;
    }
}
```

How to solve this exception while using the context tag in the configuration?

Comment: I also have this same issue. . .

Comment: How did you defined "com.spring.sample.Triangle"?

Comment: The question is updated.Please take a look.

Comment: Can you paste your MainSpringClass.java here??

Comment: Spring 3.2 is not compatible with Java 8. Use a recent enough version (the latest stable version, for example). 3.2 is really old.

Comment: it worked for me.. can you post this as answer so that this will be useful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The issue is not with the code but with the Spring Framework version. JDK 1.8 is not compatible with Spring framework: 3.2.0.RELEASE. Upgrading the spring framework resolved the issue.